# Boolean combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus

Every finite Boolean algebra has a "middle layer", corresponding to the subsets of size $n/2$ (when looking at the algebra of subsets of $[n]$) or to a set of formulas including $p_i, \neg p_i, p_i \equiv p_j, p_i \equiv \neg p_j$ – when looking at the (Lindenbaum) algebra $\mathcal{P}_k$ of propositional formulas over the variables $p_1, p_2,\dots p_k$.

Considered as **sets** the elements of the middle layer all have the same number of elements, and no distinction can be made among them.

Considered as **formulas**, a distinction *can* be made: with respect to the number of propositional variables essentially involved (see the examples above). Let me call this number simply the ***size*** of the formula.

Among the $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}$ formulas of the middle layer of $\mathcal{P}_k$, there are $c_k(1)=2k$ of size $1$ and $c_k(2)=k(k-1)$ of size $2$.

I tried and tried but did not find

> 1. a general simplest syntactical form of the formulas of size $l \geq 3$ and
> 2. their respective number, i.e. the function $c_k(l)$ for $l \geq 3$.

I tried to answer my questions by looking at truth tables, i.e. Boolean functions $f: \lbrace 0,1\rbrace^k \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ which are in 1:1 correspondence with the formulas under consideration.

One thing I found out in the course of this: The formulas of minimal size 1 correspond to the most *regular* sequences of 0s and 1s in their truth tables (with naturally ordered arguments). And the formulas of maximal size $k$ correspond to the most *irregular* sequences of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Well, if $p_i$ is not present in $\phi$ of the middle layer, then $\phi\,{\tt xor}\,p_i$ and $\phi\,{\tt xor}\,\lnot p_i$ are again there. This generalizes your original thought and shows cases for $l\ge 3$. However, this so far gives $\sum_{j=1}^k\binom kj 2^j =3^k-1$ formulas, and that is definitely not (yet) $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}$.